# Get average of time data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, date-time

How do I compute average time in my column N?

My AHT works when I only use `=AVERAGE(N6:N7)`, but when it is `=AVERAGE(N6:N755)`, it doesn't work.

Note that there are only values in N6 and N7, values in N8 onwards is 0:00:00.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", is it producing an error result or an answer that is not what you expect?  Zero is a legitimate time for an average, so that shouldn't be a reason for it not working.  If you want to exclude values of zero, you would need to explicitly do that.

Comment: @rcdcnis Could you Share Sample data with us and one more do you want result as `NUMBER or as TIME` ??

Answer (score 0):

If *"doesn't work"* means not giving you the correct answer, then use the *Array Formula:*

=`AVERAGE(IF(N6:N755=0,"",N6:N755))`

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the zero values are being included in the average when you want the average of only non-zero values.  When your data contain values that make a function like AVERAGE perform differently from what you want, sometimes a simple solution is to just calculate what you want and skip the function.  You could do that with a formula like this:

```
=SUM(N6:N755)/COUNTIF(N6:N755,">0")
```

Comment: thanks for this. this is exactly the same with what I came up to solve the problem :)